# Edit Line Numbers in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For one of the side products, I wish to manipulate line numbers that are shown on the editor in eclipse. Basically for few lines, I wish to show it in below order:

```
1 
2 
3 
3_1 
3_2 
3_3 
4
and so..
```

Which class handles the line numbers. I tried looking at source and found `MarkerField` and  but it is not very helpful. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

`org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn` is responsible to display line numbers. `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberChangeRulerColumn` extends above for other minor adjustments.

This is and initialized and used by `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`. `TextEditor` extends above and it is the default one used by eclipse. So to manipulate, there is a lot to be done respectively in each class.

I hope someone can provide a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

Ruler columns are contributed using the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns` extension point.

The existing line number column is contributed using this mechanism and uses the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.LineNumberColumn` class to show the `LineNumberChangeRulerColumn` mentioned in @Jatin's answer.

It would be hard to change the existing line number ruler column, much easier to add a new column.